# give control to the servlet when the project is started (javaEE)

Tags: servlets

a solution is to set the web.xml file this way

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but for some strange reason then the css does not work well
(works only with a online css)

another solution could be to set the web.xml file this way

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

right button -> property -> run
and set Context path
and relative URL
in this way

[image]

in a web project it works (I think)
but it does not work in a JavaEE project
right now I use an index.html file as a start page. (but I do not like it as a solution)
another solution is to put all the CSS online, but it's not a good solution

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I would like that:
((when the application starts it must give control to the servlet)
AND
(the application must see the CSS))
how can I have both at the same time?